# Attic Fan coil short cycles in heat mode

Tags: hvac

[image]My attic fan coil unit (MBX-HW) fan will short cycle in heat mode.  On for 20sec  off for 20sec.  Worked fine in cool mode last Summer.
Replaced the filter, thermostat replaced 2 years ago.  The heat is or seems to be maintained as my wife isn't complaining :)    Unit is easily accessible.  Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: Has it always cycled like this or is this something new?  Check that the thermal cutout switch is  clean.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. We'll need more info before we can help you. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, much appreciated, where is this switch located.

Comment: I have a picture of what I think might be the thermal cutout switch, can pics be posted here?   I do not see an option

Comment: I added the pics to my original post, thanks

Comment: I take it this is a hydronic air handler we're dealing with here?